# Can I say this: "How is traffic congestion that of a massive problem?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction

Are there any grammar mistakes in the sentence? Specifically, I'd like to know if it's in the correct order and if I can use "that of a" in it.

Comment: You definitely *can't* say exactly that, no. But you could ask *How is traffic congestion that **much** of a massive problem?* See the many written instances of [***It's not that much of a problem***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22not+that+much+of+a+problem%22) in Google Books.

Comment: Also *How is traffic congestion such a massive problem*. I agree with the ban on "That much of a" stated here.

Answer (score 0):

I think how you have asked the question is wrong.

Instead you can ask

*How is traffic congestion a massive problem?*

And I have to say No, you cant use 'That of a' in this question.

more, to understand 'That of a'

Maybe this will help?[What is the usage of "that of " in the following sentence: "The situation is analogous to that of a bubble"? Can we write "The situation is analogous to a bubble" instead of the previous sentence?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-usage-of-that-of-in-the-following-sentence-The-situation-is-analogous-to-that-of-a-bubble-Can-we-write-The-situation-is-analogous-to-a-bubble-instead-of-the-previous-sentence)